# How to avoid one hot encoding again and again on each run

Tags: machine-learning, python

I have a dataset which is categorical. I did one hot encoding in the train data which is taking much time for each run of my algorithm. I have also performed one hot encoding on the test data which I give at the run time to the algorithm. I want to know how can we avoid the one hot encoding of the dataset for each run, rather I want it to be done only on the new test data.

I am working on classification problem using Decision tree classifier.My dataset is categorical so I have done one hot encoding on the dataset as well as on the active user input given at the run time . It takes too much time while doing encoding in dataset. I wish , if once one hot encoding is done on training dataset, I should not do it again and again on each run and to perform encoding only the active test input i.e. on 'a'.

```
features = [0,1,2,4,5,6,7,8]
X = dataset.iloc[:,features]
y = dataset.iloc[:,3]
X_ordinal = X.values

encoder = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown = 'ignore')
encoder.fit(X_ordinal)
X_one_hot = enc.transform(X_ordinal)
end4 = time.clock()


print("enter the inputs in space separated format:" )
start5 = time.clock()
a = [int(p) for p in input().split()]

values=array(a)
X_test_one_hot=encoder.transform(values.reshape(1, -1))
```

Comment: Welcome to the Site! can you explain a bit on why are doing it and what are you trying to achieve by doing this? if you can explain more then we can suggest you better.

Comment: I am working on classification problem using Decision tree classifier.My dataset is categorical so I have done one hot encoding on the dataset as well as on the active user input given at the run time . It takes too much time while doing encoding in dataset. I wish , if once one hot encoding is done on training dataset, I should not do it again and again on each run and to perform encoding only the active test input.

Comment: I have added my code sample. For one hot encoding of dataset it always takes 3 min on each run of the algorithm. I want to avoid it.

Comment: Use `pickle` module. If you used IPython/Jupyter you could also use `%store` magic.

Comment: Make your own wrapper or store your data to easily loadable formats  like feather,npz,pickle etc

Comment: Also it's not at all compulsory to one hot encoding, there are other better ways as one hot expands the columns exponentially, Also make sure that you are not one hot encoding a $prinary key or the index of the table...$ as it will take forever....

Comment: @Aditya I am doing the one hot encoding by taking the attribute name of the column.